# Trying to make UITableView's tableHeaderView outside of table bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to add a "cap" to my table. It's when you move your table down and see that it's organically ending above. It's necessary because of custom cells. I assumed it's better done with tableHeaderView, but it's added to tableView content and is present as part of table. I want it to be hidden and only visible when you move table from it's scope and it should bounce back.

```
|*cap here*|
|==========| <- top of device
|top cell  |
rest of table...
```

Hope this perfectly drawn schematic helps to understand my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your view on top of your tableview

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - yourHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, yourHeight)];
[self.tableView addSubview:view];
```

then, add this in the scrollViewDidScroll method of your tableview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

For more information look at this project

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Comment: Your answer is correct. To make "cap" I just had to add subview with negative origin. "viewDidScroll" wasn't necessary. Thanks.